# Why do I get an error while trying to add projection layers to a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a code from tensorflow 1.8 to tensorflow 2.x, but there's a function that supposedly creates a projection layer for each layer, from a certain layer to the initial layer.
This is the original code

```
def proj_func(input, layer: Layer):
    if isinstance(layer, (Dense, Conv2D)):
        input = tf.nn.relu(input)
    output = tf.gradients(layer.output, layer.input, grad_ys=input)
    return output

for idx in range(from_idx, to_idx, -1):
    new_layer = Lambda(proj_func, arguments={'layer': layers[idx]}, name=layers[idx-1].name+'_proj')
    x = new_layer(x)
    layers[idx-1].related_projection = new_layer
```

New code

```
def proj_func(layer):
    def func(input):
        if isinstance(layer, (Dense, Conv2D)):
            input = tf.nn.relu(input)
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            output = layer(input)
        grads = tape.gradient(output, layer.trainable_variables)
        return grads
    return func
for idx in range(from_idx, to_idx, -1):
    new_layer = Lambda(proj_func(layers[idx]), name=layers[idx - 1].name + '_proj')
    x = new_layer(x)
    layers[idx - 1].related_projection = new_layer
```

With this new code I get the following error while trying to project on a Dense layer, that has input shape of 1024 and output shape of 512.

```
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "flatten_1_proj" (type Lambda).

Input 0 of layer "dense_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 512, but received input with shape (None, 1024)

Call arguments received by layer "flatten_1_proj" (type Lambda):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32)
  • mask=None
  • training=None
```

I tried changing the func to a Layer, to a tf.function, tried using tf.gradients, nothings seems to work as in the original, which also I have not tried, since creating the environment required needs too many old packages.